# Should I use a logging framework with ASP.NET MVC 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, logging

I'm getting ready for my first ASP.NET MVC 2 project and was wondering whether ASP.NET Tracing
is sufficient for any logging I might need to do.  Is anyone using a logging framework like log4net or NLog with an ASP.NET MVC 2 application, and if so, what additional functionality
does it provide that ASP.NET Tracing lacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A year later, I guess I can answer my own question.  I ended up using [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/), and overall have found it very easy to use, with one exception:  to allow NLog to write to a file when the ASP.NET MVC site is running in IIS (vs. Cassini), you have to grant the appropriate permissions to the folder for the App Pool user.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out ELMAH. It does a lot for you. http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/MVC

Comment: Yup, I guess I didn't totally get what you wanted. In any case tracing isn't really what you want running outside of developement/debugging purposes. When you want to log an important event within a project I would use log4net or better yet Common.Logging http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/ which supports a few logging libraries. You can also use them for debugging puposes by calling the Debug method if you wanted to... Use the right tool for the right job.

Answer (score 0):

[GIBRALTAR](http://www.GibraltarSoftware.com) is an option if you're willing to consider a commercial solution.  It integrates ASP.NET Tracing, ELMAH-like exception logging and ASP.NET Health Monitoring.

If you're interested, we have videos, full documentation and live chat on our website along with a full-featured 30-day trial.